# How to handle empty array as params with $fetch?

Tags: nuxt.js, query-string, supabase

i am building a search interface with filters and searchbox. The framework i'm using is Nuxt3.

On the one hand I use $fetch to query my api with params from the search page.
`

```
const { data: cheeses, refresh } = await useAsyncData('cheeses', 
  () => $fetch("/api/v1/cheese", {
    params: {
      name: modele.value.name,
      regions: JSON.stringify(modele.value.regions),
      curd_types: JSON.stringify(modele.value.curd_types),
      milk_types: JSON.stringify(modele.value.milk_types),
      aoc: modele.value.aoc
    }
  })
);
```

On the other I retrieve these params to build a supabase query in my custome API.

```
export default eventHandler(async (event) => {
  const client = serverSupabaseClient(event);
  
  // retrieve params
  const query = await getQuery(event)
  const filterByName = query.name;
  const filterByRegion = query.regions;
  const filterByCurdType = query.curd_types;
  const filterByMilkType = query.milk_types;
  const filterByAOC = query.aoc;

  // initializing the request
  let querySupabase = client.from('cheeses').select() 
  
  // applying filters if needed
  if (filterByName)  { querySupabase = querySupabase.ilike('name', '%' + filterByName + '%') }
  if (filterByAOC)  { querySupabase = querySupabase.eq('aoc', filterByAOC) }
  if (filterByRegion)  { 
    const regions = JSON.parse(filterByRegion)
    querySupabase = querySupabase.overlaps('regions', regions) 
  }
  if (filterByCurdType)  {
    const curd_types =  JSON.parse(filterByCurdType)
    querySupabase = querySupabase.overlaps('curd_type', curd_types) 
  }
  if (filterByMilkType)  { 
    const milk_types = JSON.parse(filterByMilkType)
    querySupabase = querySupabase.overlaps('milk_types', milk_types)
  }
  
  // making the request
  const { data, error } = await querySupabase
    .order("name", { ascending: true });

  // "handling" the error
  if (error !== null){
    return error
  } else {
    return data
  }
})
```

The search page contains several filter with multiple selection (I store these options in an array), which are used in $fetch as params. It works fine but I don't know how to handle the reset of filters.

My components are linked with the data (called "modele" in the code, a JS object) with v-model.

I tried different solutions:

1. The reset function "deletes" every entry of the modele and updates the query:

```
async function reinitializeFilters() {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(modele.value)) {
    delete modele.value[key];
  }
  await updateQuery();
}
```

It effectively empties the modele, and the query, but my components aren't emptied of the selected values.

2. The reset functions sets to "null" every entry the modele and updates the query:

```
async function reinitializeFilters() {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(modele.value)) {
    modele.value[key] = null;
  }
  await updateQuery();
}
```

This time, the components are reset (on the interface), but the query returns an error as I'm trying to JSON.stringify a null.

I'm not sure of the best way to consider a "reset" function for query params (especially when they are arrays). What are the best practices in that field ?
Thanks a lot for your help!

I tried different solutions:

The reset function "deletes" every entry of the modele and updates the query:

```
async function reinitializeFilters() {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(modele.value)) {
    delete modele.value[key];
  }
  await updateQuery();
}
```

It effectively empties the modele, and the query, but my components aren't emptied of the selected values.

2. The reset functions sets to "null" every entry the modele and updates the query:

```
async function reinitializeFilters() {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(modele.value)) {
    modele.value[key] = null;
  }
  await updateQuery();
}
```

This time, the components are reset (on the interface), but the query returns an error as I'm trying to JSON.stringify a null.

I'm not sure of the best way to consider a "reset" function for query params (especially when they are arrays). What are the best practices in that field ?

Thanks a lot for your help!